# How to create schema in Spark with Scala if more than 100 columns in the input?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, case-class

with case class we have some restrictions...
with StructType is it possible to for 100+ columns,
Is there any other way to create scheme for around 600+ columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val columns = (1 to 600).map(i => s"Column_$i").map(cname => StructField(cname, StringType))
val schemaWithSixHundredsColumns = StructType(columns)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(new java.util.ArrayList[Row](), schemaWithSixHundredsColumns)
```

Comment: Thanks @pasha701 its working...I think it will create default column names `Column_*,StringType` .So if we want with custom column names and data types ..we can read list of columns from file and create it right?

Comment: yes, names and types can be taken from file or other source.

Comment: Hi @pasha701 I am trying below for custom name and data type.  `Schema.csv:
label_header_10,StringType
label_0x00da_1_Charge_Start_time,IntegerType,
label_0x00da_2,IntegerType
`   `val schema = sc.textFile("C:\\Users\\z031235\\Downloads\\Spark_POC\\src\\Data\\Schema.csv         val columns_m=schema.map(l => l.split(",")).map(l=> StructField(l(0) , StringType))
val schemaWithSixHundredsColumns = StructType(columns_m)`                            
 error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  (fields: array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types....

Comment: val collectedColumns = columns_m.collect()
    val schemaWithSixHundredsColumns = StructType(collectedColumns)